# Landlines and IP Phones

Tags: ip, cisco-7900-ip-phones

The video I am watching mentions the following information
[image]

I always thought of these traditional/landline phones as an old technology that is not used anymore, but this was just from a home's perspective. However, are these traditional landlines still used in businesses? Or have they been replaced by IP phones?

And would it be possible to make a call from a cell phone to an IP phone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's "old" technology, but there are many, many places where it's still used.   Converting to IP phone is expensive and time consuming. Companies usually only switch to IP Phones when they have to.

Comment: That depends on the country - landlines are commonly still used with xDSL and being slowly replaced by fiber. However, questions about networks not under your control are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic], and technically your question is too broad. Cell phones, POTS phones and IP phones are all interconnected by PSTN, even if it's not circuit-switched any more.

Comment: It should also be mentioned, in business settings there have been many generations of analog and digital technologies between POTS and VoIP. Nortel, Toshiba, Samsung, etc. all have/had proprietary PBX systems. (One we had decades ago from Avaya was surprisingly using ISDN... under their proprietary stuff.)

Comment: The PSTN is still a thing. Very different from what it was many decades ago. For example, a great deal of phone traffic is carried over "IP" today. But there's still *a lot* of old hardware out there -- DMS100's and 5ESS's.